# Phpstorm как в файле изменить отступы?

Tags: phpstorm

Смотрите, есть настройки для каждого типа файлов, допустим, html. Я указал там отступы табуляции 2, чтоб поуже было.

Но в некоторых файлах остались отступы 4. Т.е. очень широкий код получается, а я люблю пользоваться автоформатированием.

Вот и как в этих файлах принудительно изменить отступы? на 2. Настройки уже изменены. Но на некоторые файлы не влияет.

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно переформатировать код **Code|Reformat Code**. Более детально в [официальной документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reformatting-source-code.html)

Comment: я ж говорю пользуюсь автоформатированием. ctrl alt shift + L 
Но в некоторых он делает по старым отступам! 4 отступа. а я настроил 2. мелочь, но хочу чтоб везде было по 2 отступа

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг, насколько я помню, если настроить, например, для HTML 2 отступа, а для PHP — 4, то при автоформатировании в PHP-файле IDE сделает для разметки также 4 отступа.

Answer (score 3):

1. Ctrl+Alt+S (File→Settings)
2. Editor→Code Style→HTML (название вашего языка)
3. Необходимо изменить Tab size, Ident, Continuation ident — я ставлю все 2.
4. Если пользуетесь пробелами, а не табами необходимо снять галочку Use tab character (я снял).
5. В окне редактирования файла нажать Ctrl+Alt+L (Code→Reformat Code)

Answer (score 3):

6. Если всё равно после Ctrl+Alt+L (Code→Reformat Code) ставит пробелы, попробуйте снять галочку с Enable EditorConfig support (File→Settings→Editor→Code Style)

Answer (score 0):

Снять галку Editor->Code Style->Enable EditorConfig support
или отредактировать .editorconfig в корне проекта.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-code-style.html#